# Generate normal and minified css file with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a task that generates the css of the scss files in the following way

```
const css = () => {
 return src('src/scss/index.scss')
  .pipe(mode.development( sourcemaps.init() ))
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(rename('app.css'))
  .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
  .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
}
```

Is there any way to generate 2 files, one minified and one "normal" file?

Comment: You can have multiple `gulp.dest()` calls.  Just put one before it is minified (i.e., before any `pipe`s you want to save before) and the one at the end.

Comment: @Mark Thank you it worked!